# MYSQL query using Left Join and Where IN clause

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have three tables A B C and i'm trying to retrieve information from all three.

A has the columnns userid avatar username and B has the column postid, dateshared and C has the column commenter postid datecommented.

I'm trying to run the query

```
Select  C.comment, C.commenter,  C.datecommented, B.postid, B.dateshared A.username A.avatar from B Left Join C  Left join A on C.postid = B.postid AND A.userid = C.commenter where B.postid IN ('1','2','3') order by  C.dateshared desc
```

but it gives the following error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where B.postid IN ('1', '2', '3') order by C.dateshared '
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong or suggest how to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `LEFT JOIN` requires its own `ON` condition:

```
SELECT  C.comment, C.commenter, C.datecommented, B.postid, B.dateshared, A.username A.avatar
FROM    B
LEFT JOIN
        C
ON      C.postid = B.postid
LEFT JOIN
        A
ON      A.userid = C.commenter
WHERE   B.postid IN ('1','2','3')
ORDER BY
        C.dateshared desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, your query had some syntax errors:

```
Select  C.comment,C.commenter,C.datecommented,B.postid,B.dateshared,A.username,A.avatar
from B
Left Join C on C.postid = B.postid
Left join A on A.userid = C.commenter
where B.postid IN ('1','2','3')
order by  C.dateshared desc
```